# Why I get a req.app.locals.something undefined?

Tags: node.js, express

In my server.js I have:

```
app.locals.users = connectedUsers;
```

connectedUsers is an object.

I want to access it from controllers but I always get undefined.
This is how I want to access it:

```
req.app.locals.users
```

I've used the same code in a project before and it worked.

What could it be?

Comment: For every request req is renewed. You can use session storage or cookies

Comment: I use cookieSession with passport for authentication. I taught it would be stored there.

Comment: I've found out the problem. I had to put {withCredentials:true} on request.